# I want to toggle a button from GUI tkinter and display a counts from GPIO

Tags: gpio, tkinter, gpiozero

I want to toggle a button from GUI tkinter and display a counts from GPIO.

Here I have a counter system code:

```
from gpiozero import *
from time import sleep

#####GPIO input##########

led = LED(26)
sensor = LineSensor(24)

#####Global variable#####
counts = 0

def number():
    global counts
    counts += 1
    print(counts)

while True:
    if sensor.is_active:
        sleep(1.5)
        number()
        print("detected" + str(counts))
        led.blink(on_time=.05, off_time=.05, n=2)

pause()
```

Then, from this code I want to display it on a tkinter after toggle a button.
I've made some try:

```
from tkinter import *
from gpiozero import *
from time import sleep


root = Tk()
root.title('Counter')
root.geometry('250x250')

led = LED(26)
sensor = LineSensor(24)

counts = 0

def number():
    global counts
    counts += 1

while True:
    if sensor.is_active:
        sleep(1.5)
        number()
        led.blink(on_time=.05, off_time=.05, n=2)

StartCount = Button(root, text="Start count", font=('arial', 12), fg='black', command=number)
StartCount.pack()
CountsValue = Label(root, font=('arial', 16), text=counts, fg='black')
CountsValue.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Then nothing happen. Can anyone help me with this, i'm still studying this.

Comment: You might find this easier using guizero (a simple wrapper around Tk): https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/traffic-lights-controller-gui/

Comment: that would be good, but i wanted to create a tkinter ones, do u have any suggestion for that?

Comment: Where is the problem with Raspberry Pi? Does it work on other platforms?

Comment: The problem is, nothing showing when i start running it. doesn't work also. I wanted to toggle a button from tkinter and then my counting will start and shows the value into tkinter also